# Age: stream cipher with public key cryptography?

Tags: public-key, symmetric, stream-cipher, chacha

I have some rudimentary cryptography knowledge but am by no means an expert.

I generally understand stream ciphers, such as such as ChaCha20-Poly1305, to be symmetric. I am wondering how age (https://github.com/FiloSottile/age) uses public and private keys to encrypt data with ChaCha20-Poly1305. Is it similar to how in some protocols asymmetric encryption is used to establish a shared symmetric key, or is age’s protocol entirely different? If so, what is the asymmetric algorithm used to share the symmetric key?

If there’s a broader concept that I’m missing here, I would love any recommendations for introductory further reading.

Comment: It's X25519 key exchange between an ephemeral key pair and the recipient's public key.  Yes, it's a standard approach that is used widely elsewhere

Comment: It seems that `scrypt` is also an option as "recipient type". For the protocol for X25519 it seems that the *identity* is the party that decrypts using the static private key (also called `identity`, nice), and `recipient` consists of the static public key.  The ephemeral keys are called `ephemeral secret` which is what we normally call a private key and the public key is called `ephemeral share` (ugh), which are used to calculate an `shared secret`. I'm not sure who was naming things here, but it is **very** confusing. Must be the "stanza" thing or something, poetic :|

Answer (score 2):

The specification for age is [here](https://github.com/C2SP/C2SP/blob/main/age.md). As explained in the *X25519 recipient stanza* [section](https://github.com/C2SP/C2SP/blob/main/age.md#x25519-recipient-stanza), an ephemeral key pair is generated, and the ephemeral private key is used to perform an X25519 key exchange with the recipient public key. This computes a shared secret that's used to derive a key using HKDF-SHA-256. Then the ephemeral public key is included in the encrypted file to allow the recipient to compute the same shared secret using their private key, enabling decryption.

```
ephemeral secret = read(CSPRNG, 32)
ephemeral share = X25519(ephemeral secret, basepoint)

salt = ephemeral share || recipient
info = "age-encryption.org/v1/X25519"
shared secret = X25519(ephemeral secret, recipient)
wrap key = HKDF-SHA-256(ikm = shared secret, salt, info)
body = ChaCha20-Poly1305(key = wrap key, plaintext = file key)
```

The downside of this approach is that it provides no sender authentication. It's like libsodium's [sealed box](https://doc.libsodium.org/public-key_cryptography/sealed_boxes) in that the sender's identity is anonymous. In the context of age, this can be considered a [design flaw](https://github.com/FiloSottile/age/discussions/229) because if you receive a file from someone, you want to know that it came from them and was not replaced by an attacker.

The best further reading on this topic is a [series](https://neilmadden.blog/2018/11/26/public-key-authenticated-encryption-and-why-you-want-it-part-ii/) of blog posts by Neil Madden on public key authenticated encryption. Part 2, which I've linked above, explains what age is doing and better alternatives.

Additionally, I would strongly recommend [Real-World Cryptography](https://www.manning.com/books/real-world-cryptography) by David Wong, which is by far the best introductory book I've come across and has some facts/stories even more experienced people may not know. It covers Curve25519/X25519 and hybrid encryption with ECIES like age is doing.

Another important thing to read is the Curve25519/X25519 [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7748.html), particularly the *Security Considerations* [section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7748.html#section-7), which has an important detail that's often overlooked. There's the original [paper](https://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf). Finally, there are various blog posts like [this](https://neilmadden.blog/2020/05/28/whats-the-curve25519-clamping-all-about/) and [this](https://loup-vaillant.fr/tutorials/cofactor).